# Is there any way to add iframe to wordpress.com?

Tags: html, wordpress, iframe, wordpress.com

I want to add an iframe to wordpress blog (.COM). However,

- Wordpress editor deletes immediately after updating the page (I write both text section (via HTML) and visual section)
- Plugins don't work with .com
- I have no access to functions.php

Is there any way to add iframe wordpress.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

frame, iframe, form, input, object, textarea tags are not allowed in WordPress.com posts, pages, or text widgets on the Premium Plan and below.
But Business plan supports the same along with installation of third party plugins and theme.